# window.indexedDB in IE11 is undefined

Tags: html, indexeddb, internet-explorer-11

I have a indexedDB web app which works fine in IE10 but not in IE11. The problem is that in IE11 window.indexedDB is undefined. Is IndexedDB still supported in IE11? If so, how do you open a IndexedDB database without window.indexedDB?

My Test HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

Output from F12 Developer Tools console:

```
window.indexedDB
undefined
window.msIndexedDB
undefined
window.navigator.userAgent
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: I don't think so. When I add my site to the Compatibility View Settings list, the userAgent contains the text "compatible". The full userAgent string in compatibility mode for me is : "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0)". The userAgent string in the original test above did not contain the text "compatible".

Comment: It's working fine for me. What is the value of `document.documentMode` and `document.compatMode` in the console?

Comment: are you load your html in valid origin?

Comment: My document.documentMode is 11 and my document.compatMode is CSS1Compat.

Comment: The origin is valid and works fine from Windows 8 IE10. The same URL in Windows 8.1 IE11 has the indexedDB undefined problem.

Comment: I experienced same problem. None of the online samples were working unless I did click "Reset..." in "Advanced" tab of Internet Options. I have no clue which exact setting is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resetting the IE settings to the defaults, everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in debug mode, default document mode is set to 9.
IE 9 doesn't support indexeddb.
Go to Developer tool, and set Documentation mode to 10 or above.

br,
Jan